# Reactjs hide navbar in all component have path = /admin/

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to hide my navbar when i'm in all page have path='/admin/...' but it's so length. How can i clean it, thank very much.

```
let HideHeader = window.location.pathname === '/admin/info' && '/admin/setting' && '/admin/post' && '/admin/messange' ? null : <MyNav username={username} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple string methods like `startsWith()`, `search()`, `indexOf()`, `includes()`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

**startsWith**

`window.location.pathname.startsWith('/admin')`

This will return true if your URL starts with /admin

**search**

`(window.location.pathname.search('/admin') !== -1)`

This will return true if your URL contains /admin

**indexOf**

`(window.location.pathname.indexOf('/admin') !== -1)`

This will return true if your URL contains /admin

Answer (score 0):

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
let HideHeader = window.location.pathname.indexOf('/admin/') === 0 ? null : <MyNav username={username} />
```

It will test for pathname that starts with `/admin/`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `includes()` method:

`let HideHeader = window.location.pathname.includes('/admin/') ? null : <MyNav username={username} />`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method with regex

```js
let HideHeader =  !window.location.pathname.match(/\/admin.*/g) && <MyNav username={username} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient, semantically correct and understandable solution - [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith):

```
window.location.pathname.startsWith('/admin');
```